# How to login twitter app rather than Safari web in react native?

Tags: react-native, twitter-login

I use **react-native-simple-auth** in my project but i can login twitter in web.I want to login with twitter app instead of safari view in react native. How to do this? Any Idea?

Comment: Twitter app installed on your mobile?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed Twitter in the phone use this:

```
Linking.openURL('twitter://app')
```

This is the snippet that open an external app. It open but you can't pass params to log in. Only open the app and, if you are logged, you will automatically enter to the app logged, else, just will open Login view.

Comment: Thanks your answer but actually i want to do if the twitter application is installed on the phone, i want to login twitter native app. How to do this?

Comment: You cannot do it, you can't order to another apps things that they are not ready to handle. No mobile apps are ready to handle other apps order they to do something like login, is not the same as web navigator